# How to destroy activity from view? or how to destroy both of them?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-view, ondestroy

I created an Activity and a View for my apps.
Inside the view, I have one thread that acts like a server.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MainView(this));
}
}

public class ServerView extends View {

public ServerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
        server.startServer();
}
}
```

when I pressed backButton, My apps wasnt destroyed.I destroyed it manually, but my thread is still running in the background. I need to catch backButton event so I used this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
    server.shutDown();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

this function cant stop my Thread. I dont know how to destroy my mainActivity from the view?
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in main activity and access it from your server view

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        server.shutDown();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

access activity object in your server view and call this code

Answer (score 0):

You'd better override [`Activity.finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method and clear any occupied resources (like `server.shutDown()` in your case) there.

Answer (score 0):

simply call `finish()` it will work as you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use finish() method to destroy your activity. And to destroy your thread running in background use return statement or,

```
if(thread != null)
{
    Thread t1 = thread;
    thread = null;
    t1.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion，if you want to destroy Activity，you can use `Activity.finish()`.
if you want destroy any Thread,you can`System.exit(0);`